# How can I find open questions and answers that I haven't seen?

Tags: support, feature-request

[I like to vote!](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Voters&filter=all)

When I do a good job of keeping it up, my voting pattern is such that the ratio of my total number of votes to total number of posts is at least half.  (For example, as of today, June 1, 2017, I've voted over 13,000 times, which is over half of the current number of approximately 20,000 questions and answers we have on the site, also as of today.)

It shouldn't be hard to locate open posts I haven't seen, yet it often takes a lot of time wandering around the site to find them.

I use a few methods, such as searching by tag, user, and the related questions that are on the right side of the page. I'd much prefer a quicker, easier way.

Is there a search function or filter system already in place? If so, how do I use it? If not, can one be created? The ultimate would be a list, enabling me to read each post, decide whether or not I want to vote, and move on to the next. If that's not possible, any shortcut would help.

I'm probably not the only one who'd appreciate this tool. Anything we can do to make voting easier would benefit the whole community.

I have no idea how to write queries, so if someone would be kind enough to set it up and tell me how to keep using it, I'd be very grateful!

Comment: I don't think SE tracks which questions you've seen.  So, as long as a question remains unanswered, it will remain in that queue whether you've voted on it or not.

Comment: I used to use the 'newest questions' tab and just remember which page I was on haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would mean losing functionality that you may, on balance, prefer to keep but you might choose to 'favourite' every Q once you have seen it and then select:

```
-infavorites:mine Closed:0
```

Comment: Thanks pnuts! This sounds like it would work, at least going forward. It makes me think of a related question, which I'll post separately if you'd rather. Is there a batch way to un-favorite all my favorites? I know how to find the list in my profile, but if I'm finished with them, I have un-favorite them one at a time.